# Зачем нужен auth_key Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Планирую создать простую форму авторизации / регистрации пользователя. Почитал множество гайдов о том, как это можно реализовать, и заметил, что везде в миграции (и в модели) есть `auth_key`:

```
$this->createTable('{{%user}}', [
    'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
    'username' => $this->string()->notNull()->unique(),

    // !!!
    'auth_key' => $this->string(32)->notNull(),

    'password_hash' => $this->string()->notNull(),
    'password_reset_token' => $this->string()->unique(),
    'email' => $this->string()->notNull()->unique(),
    'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
    'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
], $tableOptions);
```

Я поразмыслил, и решил делать авторизацию без него. Все вроде ок, миграцию применил, начал делать модель `User`, и столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

`'app\models\User' does not implement methods 'getAuthKey', 'validateAuthKey'`

`php` ругается, мол, не объявлены методы `getAuthKey` и `validateAuthKey`. Как можно это исправить? И зачем так сильно нужен этот самый `auth_key`?

Comment: Этот самый кей - связующее звено между сервером и клиентом, без него не заработает. Грубо говоря, вот зачем вам в базе id? auth_key то же самое, только нужно для общения браузера и сервера.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков какую-то фигню ты написал)

Comment: Просто упростил донельзя :)

Comment: Прога пишет вам вот такое: 'app\models\User' does not implement methods 'getAuthKey', 'validateAuthKey' : «Пользователь модели приложения» не реализует методы «получить ключ аутентификации», «проверить ключ аутентификации»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фреймворк для аунтентификации:

1. Смотрит id юзера в сессии. Если не нашлось, то...
2. Смотрит id и `auth_key` в куках. Туда они сохраняются только при "Запомнить меня".

Сессия по умолчанию живёт один час.

По сути, если не нужна галочка, то все эти auth_key не нужны

Comment: я правильно понял, что auth_key по сути нужен только для того, чтобы пользователь мог быть залогинен на сайте больше часа, верно? Еще вопрос - нужно ли обновлять этот auth_key (удалять старый и генерировать новый), и в каких случаях это нужно делать?

Comment: 1 - верно. 2.  регенерировать authKey можно  для того, чтобы инвалидировать куку логина....ну и для каждого нового юзера своя чтоб была конечно